# Async Input / Output CLI deno

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, command-line-interface, chat, deno

I'm building a chat program in **deno** cli. I already wrote the function that gets new messages and prints them on screen every 1 second. While it's doing this it also asynchronously listens to the cli input (using **standard deno readLines**) so when the user hits enter his message gets posted. However if you happen to be writing a message and the refresh hits before you press enter, the new messages are written right next to what you were writing and you need to type it again.

[image: terminal test]

As you can see, I was typing nonsense (`fdghsjkasjdhfv`) but *Alice* said `hello` again, the refresh function kicked in and wrote the new message right after what I was typing.

The question is: Is there a way to save the typed stuff, clear it and print it back once the refresh function has posted the new messages?

The code I'm using:

```js
import { readLines } from "https://deno.land/std/io/mod.ts";

async function read() {
    for await(const line of readLines(Deno.stdin)) {
        if (!settings.printing) return line;
    }
}

let settings = { exit: false, user: 'anon', lastID: 0, printing: false };

async function main() {
    console.log('== DISCUSSION ==========================');
    printMessages();
    do {
        let line = await read();
        if (/^!\s*(quit|exit)$/.test(line)) settings.exit = true;
        else sendMessage(line);
    } while (!exit);
}

await main();

function sendMessage(text) {
    postRequest('postMessage', {
        user: settings.user, data: text
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status != 200) {
            console.log('[Connection Error!]');
            return;
        }
    });
}

function printMessages() {
    postRequest('getDiscussion', {
        id: settings.lastID // get the messages after the lastID received
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.status != 200) return;
        response.json().then(j => {
            if (j.length != 0) settings.lastID = j[j.length - 1].id;
            settings.printing = true;
            for (const m of j) {
                const time = new Date(m.time).toTimeString().slice(0, 5);
                console.log(
                    `[${time}][${m.user}]: `,
                    m.data
                );
            }
            settings.printing = false;
            if (!settings.exit) setTimeout(printMessages, 1000);
        });
    });
}


function postRequest(api, data) {
    let form = new FormData();
    for (const property in data) {
        form.append(property, data[property]);
    }
    return fetch(`https://example.com/api/${api}.php`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: form
    });
}
```

Comment: why don't you use sockets for real time chat?

Comment: I just can't... I'm limited to php, mysql and js apis

Comment: it is very bad practice they way you are using it! there is a support of sockets in php. try it.

Comment: yeah, I know, but the assignment says to use these technologies. however the main problem is the async input / output....